# Add FragmentActivity in TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

actually I have a FragmentActivity with a Tabhost, some Fragment inside and you can slide between the different Fragment thanks to a ViewPager.
With this FragmentActivity, I would like to incorporate it into a other Tabhost, and so have the one below the other.

For the moment, I have this solution :

```
public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends ActivityGroup {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Inflate the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.testtabhost1);
    mTabHost.setup(getLocalActivityManager());

    TabSpec ts = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB1");
    ts.setContent(new Intent(this,PageGaucheFragment.class)); <--- PageGaucheFragment is the FragmentAtivity with the ViewPager that I would like to add into the TabHost

    mTabHost.addTab(ts);

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
```

It works, but ActivityGroup was deprecated :( And I don't find any other solution to solve this problem.How can I have 2 TabHost and that the second can slide between the different Fragment ?
Thanks for your answer, and sorry for my English ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html

I've used it successfully.